# C pointer and memory leak

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free, memory-leaks

Im new to C. I have seen that in many examples malloc() always pairs up with free(). But if I do something like this: say, *p = "a string" , can I free the pointer p and will it cause memory leak issue?

EDIT: thanks for all the replies!
so my question becomes: if i have *p = "a string" in a function, does that mean all the memory which is used for this function call will be automatically "freed" by the compiler when the function ends so I don't have to manually manage anything to deal with memory?

Comment: you can free it but if you dont it will not leak

Comment: Only dynamically allocated memories by malloc, calloc function we need to explicitly deallocate using `free()` function.

Comment: If you do `char *p = "a string";` then you do NOT free that memory later. That is managed by the compiler in that case since you didn't use `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - _Only dynamically allocated memories by malloc, calloc_     What about things such as `fopen()`?.

Comment: @ryyker do you apply `free()` on `fp`?!!! I use fclose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you should write `const char *p = "a string";` as it's *undefined behaviour* to modify the string literal (e.g. using statements like `p[0] = 'A';`). Dropping the `const` will get you into trouble.

And you must not try to delete the pointer memory; that's *undefined behaviour* too.

The golden rule: `malloc` and `free` are *always* paired.

Rest assured that, in your case, the memory occupied by your string literal will be released gracefully back to the operating system by the C runtime on program exit.

Comment: your last sentence, by saying on program exit, it means that if i have a functionA() which contains *p = "a string", if the functionA is being called billion times before the program exits, it will use up all the memory?

Comment: @Hugh H, perhaps if you had a particularly bad compiler then yes. But it's quite simple for a compiler to store up all string literals in a memory pool; conceptually before the program is executed.

Comment: @Hugh H Basically, every instance of "a string" in your program maps to the same part of memory. This is ok because you can't change a string literal. No matter how many times you use the string literal, it will never use more space to store it.

Comment: Which is why I would insist on `const char*` type.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not free it, and neither should you.

When you make a pointer point to e.g. a string literal, it points to memory not allocated by you. You should only free memory you explicitly allocate (with e.g. `malloc`, `calloc` or `strdup`).

Other function may allocate memory that you need to free as well, but then they should state that in their documentation.

As a general rule of thumb: If you explicitly allocate some resource (like memory or files), then you should free it too.

Comment: Mentioning there are _other_ sources of possible memory leaks, (such as `fopen()` - `fclose()` pair, etc.) +1

Answer (score 1):

When you do `*p = "a string"`, you have a pointer `p` that points to a string literal. No memory is allocated dynamically in this case. So, no need to free `p` and neither should you.

Answer (score 1):

No. "a string" is data stored in read-only-static memory and p is a pointer that points to it. You only free pointers to memory which was allocated with malloc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to free this pointer as it points to a string constant. It is actually may cause undefined behavior if you will try to free it.

The basic rule of the memory management: if you called `malloc()` to get a memory, you shoudl use `free()` to release it when you do not need it.